# Autolayout constraint wont set to edge of SuperView

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

I'm using Xcode 6 and playing around with AutoLayout to understand the changes in it.
I came up with a problem in setting the constraint to the super view.
In my viewController i add some UI elements and i want to set the leading space constraint from my TextField to the super view (like the photo shows).
When i set it the constraint wont each the edge of the superView and take a 16 point buffer space from the end of the View to the constraint.

Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add constraints without ticking 'Constrain to margins' option.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want that TextField to 'snap' to the top. Right? If so, go in your storyboard. Select your TextField and open the pin menu (the second of four icons on the bottom right of the storyboard).

The first options let you specify distances between your element and the superview. Click on the drop-down menu of the top margin and select `View (current distance = 20)` (instead of `Top Layout Guide`). You can now set this distance to 0 (or whatever you like). 
Then, before closing the menu, check the last menu `Update Frames` and select `All frames in Container`.

By accepting these changes, you may found yourself with constraints errors. You can easily fix those the same way you'd fix any constraint error.

Hope this helps.